# isolate scope won't update model - angular 1.6

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

We are trying to use a jquery time entry component in angularjs. We have a directive for the time entry component. When I try to change the ngModel from directive based on DOM value the model is not reflected. Please see the controller, index.html, app.js below.

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.timeentry.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Time {{orderPermitViews[0].permitDetails[0].effectiveTimeForDispaly}}!</p>
    <div ng-repeat="permitDetail in orderPermitViews[0].permitDetails">
      <input type="text" name="spinner" class="time-spinner" 
      time-spinner ng-model="permitDetail.effectiveTimeForDispaly" >
    </div>
  </body>

</html>

angular.module('plunker', [])

.directive('timeSpinner', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
        scope: {timeModel: "=ngModel"},
        link: function( scope, elem, attrs) {
            $(elem).timeEntry({
                        spinnerImage: 'assets/img/spinnerUpDown.png', 
                        spinnerSize: [15, 16, 0], 
                        spinnerBigSize: [30, 32, 0], 
                        spinnerIncDecOnly: true,
                        show24Hours: true
                    }).change(function () {
                 scope.timeModel = $(elem).timeEntry('getTime');
                          console.log("Time model:" + scope.timeModel);
                    });

                    scope.$watch('timeModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                        $(elem).timeEntry('setTime', newValue);
                        console.log("Set time:" + newValue);
                    });
         }
    }
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var permitDetails = new Array();
  $scope.orderPermitViews = new Array();
  $scope.orderPermitViews[0] = {};
  $scope.orderPermitViews[0].permitDetails = new Array();
  $scope.orderPermitViews[0].permitDetails[0] = {};
  $scope.orderPermitViews[0].permitDetails[0].effectiveTimeForDispaly = new Date();

});
```

When I change the  text, I see the change function getting executed and update the model. However it is not reflected in the HTML {{orderPermitViews[0].permitDetails[0].effectiveTimeForDispaly}}. I need some help in figuring out what is going wrong here.

Comment: Here is the link to the timeEntry component where you can download the JS, CSS http://keith-wood.name/timeentry.html

Comment: Try to use scope.apply function may be this would be digest cycle issue.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Awesome! it worked.